# Can I display html tags like links and span tags inside the description in RSS feed code?

Tags: php, rss

Can I display html tags like links and span tags inside the description in RSS feed code using PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSS feed is not a html document. My answer is that you should not use html elements inside RSS feeds. At least there is no guarantee that every implementations would show them like you expect if any.

Comment: so strip out the tags using strip_tags()